# When Features shown on Google IO are available?

Tags: android

When those features shown on Google IO 2011 Android tools are available in Eclipse adt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are available today: go to source.android.com to learn how to download Android's source code. You can build your own copy of ADT and start using the features shown at I/O.